# ActiveRecord: find uniqs in specific query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, distinct

I have a query where i'm specifically trying to get uniq schools grouped by year. Can't seem to figure it out. Students have many attendances, Schools have many students. The below gives me each time a school was represented each year but i'd like each time a school was **uniquely** represented.

```
Attendance.
  joins(:student => :school).
  order("count_all DESC").
  group("schools.name").
  group_by_year('attendances.created_at').
  where(:students => { :school_id => 1}).
  count
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Postgres though i'd prefer to kept it a ActiveRecord query. The "group_by_year" method is a gem called 'by_star'

Comment: please post your database scheme/relations

Comment: i can't find `group_by_year` in `by_star` description. May be you are using `groupdate` gem?

Comment: Attendance has many Students. Schools has many students. The above gets me all times any school is represented grouped by year. I'd like to get the number of unique schools grouped by year.

Comment: If you just want to do a .count, I think this will work Schools.find(1).students.count

Comment: Attendance.joins(:student => :school).where('schools.id = ?', 1).group_by{ |m| m.created_at.beginning_of_year }.count is this what you're looking for ?